# Doing a post request in C# results in strange output

Tags: c#, json, rest, webclient

I'm doing a post request to several severs. These servers return all json except one. One of them returns data like this: 1fe2 80b9 0800 0000 0000 0400 c3ac c2bd.

If I do the same with a rest client I get from all servers valid Json but when I do it in c# one of the servers returns that kind of data.

I use the following code to do this:

```
public static string MakeRequest(string url, string requestBody, string methodName)
        {
            string result = "";
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json"; 
                result = client.UploadString(string.Format("{0}{1}", url, methodName), "POST", requestBody);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I also tried with this (old code):

```
public static string MakeRequestA(string url, string requestBody, string methodName)
        {
            byte[] postBytes        = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody);

            var request     = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", url, methodName));
            request.KeepAlive       = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            request.Method          = "POST";
            request.ContentType     = "application/json";
            request.Accept          = "text/plain";
            request.ContentLength   = postBytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);  

            var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            var reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);  
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();  

            reader.Close ();  
            dataStream.Close ();  
            response.Close ();  
            return responseFromServer;
        }
```

I can't really give you the server urls because they are private. Anybody a clue why I'm getting this data instead of valid json?

Comment: You might need to add user agent and host into the header of your request. Recently I worked with a web service which couldn't process the request without proper user agent.

Comment: Get [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) profiler and see what is sent to the server in both cases and you'll be able to see the difference.

Comment: Indeed you may need to add more headers, although I'm not sure which. For a list see here: https://www.soapui.org/testing-dojo/best-practices/understanding-rest-headers-and-parameters.html

Comment: You could also try using the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).
Check this [Comparison Article](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/)

Comment: It may be a GZIP file.  When a client and server make an HTTP connection an negotiation occurs using the headers.  It appears that a different mode is being used on the server that doesn't work from the others.  The negotiated mode is in the headers in the response.  So I would compare the headers in the good response with the bad response.  Using fiddler is one way of getting the response headers.

Comment: Hi all sorry that I answer so lately! It is like jdweng says it is a gzip file but postman automatically unzip this and outputs the json... Thank you all for helping me out! I should have checked the response header!

Answer (score 0):

HI please install fiddler tool in your machine, and with that check the request header which generated by REST client. And capture the request header which generated by .net client. Then compare both request formats to find the solution

Comment: Please do this in comment section. This can not be considered an answer.